# Resource distribution to the running Spark jobs

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am working on hadoop cluster(1+2)nodes(having total 16 vcores and 32GB ram) and I have configured spark on top of it, Now when I am trying to execute 6 application parallely, it is allocation 5 vcores to one of the application and 1 vcores each to other application. And still 10 vcores are free. What could be the reason behind this and how can I allocate more resources to the running applications.I want to make sure all the resources are being used for those 6 applications.

I tried to reduce the drive vcores and executor vcores in the script but it is not giving the expected results.